# How to remove line in header?

Tags: header-footer, rules

I am using `mdframed` in header but line still appears as shown below. How can I remove that line?.

[image]
Regards

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: isn't it called `mdframded`?

Comment: @Timebandit `mdframed` `;-)`

Comment: @Harish Kumar my bad, it's to early `;-)` i'll edit the question maybe we find someone to answer this question afterwards

Comment: @Timebandit I doubt that this question gets some answers in its current form :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the `fancyhdr` to make the header, simply redefine `\headrule` to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand\headrule{}
```